# Influence of Maturity and Yield on Convexity

Tags: convexity

I recently took a quiz in which one question asked me to choose one answer that is true regarding convexity. One of the answers said that a longer maturity leads to a higher convexity, another answer said that a lower yield leads to higher convexity.

I personally thought both are correct.

1. For the first answer I came to the conclusion that bonds with a longer maturity are much more sensitive to changes in interest rates. Since convexity is the derivative of duration that should also apply for the former.
2. For the second answer I looked at the formula of convexity and saw that the yield is in the denominator meaning that if yields fall, the whole term increases.

I d be happy if somebody could tell me what is wrong with my conclusion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @noob2! Could you give me an example of where the opposite is the case. I have not fully understood yet where exactly I mix the terms up. Does duration not increase with maturity? (I am aware they are not the same thing)

Comment: @Maths student G: I would say that duration increases with maturity. Consider zero coupon bond, it is trivial to show that for zero coupon bond duration is just time - hence duration increases when maturity increases. But we can find special case when maturity won't increase duration: when we have almost perpetual bond (think 300 years+), then the duration won't increase w.r.t maturity because future cashflows in the distant future are weighted by numerical 0 hence do not affect duration.

Comment: Another special case is FRN, maturity won't affect duration, when we value FRN with one yield curve (forwarding and discounting).